# Alternative way to write the equation

Tags: uniform-distribution

Is there any an alternative way to write this equation:

**X = 2 * r1 * r2^(1/d) - r3^(1/d)**

r1 r2 and r3 are uniform random numbers in interval (0,1)

d : it can be 10, 30 or 50

X is a vector [1,d],

For example:

```
X(1) = = 2 * r1 * r2^(1/d) - r3^(1/d)**
```

generate new r1, r2 r3

```
X(2) = = 2 * r1 * r2^(1/d) - r3^(1/d)**
```

generate new r1, r2 r3

```
X(3) = = 2 * r1 * r2^(1/d) - r3^(1/d)** 
.
.
.
```

generate new r1, r2 r3

```
X(d) = = 2 * r1 * r2^(1/d) - r3^(1/d)**
```

Comment: Do you want the PDF of X and are $r_1$,$r_2$,$r_3$ independent?

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz would you please [check this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html). 
r1 = rand(); r2=rand(); r3=rand();

X is a vector its length =d, generated using for _loop_ r1, r2 and r3 will be changed at each iteration